# Gridview getChildAt error Attempt to invoke virtual method findViewById() on null object

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I have a gridview, in which i have 24 odd elements.

Ive given the grid a fixed height so scroller appears w.r.t the elements not displayed.

My issue is
say given below is my gridview ,where the red line signifies the end of the visible grid and to see below the red line one has to scroll

[image]

say i select 6 then scroll and select 22 then again scroll up and select 11
my app crashes with the following error.

```
Exception is: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
at com.adamas.ui.AddNewBuyEntryActivity$2.onItemClick(AddNewBuyEntryActivity.java:205)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

**if i dont give my grid a fixed height and let it wrap without scroll my app doesnt crash in this scenario.**

error occurs at

```
 ((ImageView) parent.getChildAt(previousSelectedShapePosition).findViewById(R.id.img_sales_shape))
                            .setImageResource(shapeIcons.getResourceId(previousSelectedShapePosition, -1));
```

code snippet where crash occurs[im using previous position and current position to toggle the colors of selected and previously selected elements]

```
grdShapes.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            previousSelectedShapePosition = currentSelectedShapePosition;
            currentSelectedShapePosition = position;

            if (spnShape.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Polished")) {
                ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_sales_shape)).setImageResource(shapeSelectedIcons.getResourceId(position, 1));

                ((ImageView) parent.getChildAt(previousSelectedShapePosition).findViewById(R.id.img_sales_shape))
                        .setImageResource(shapeIcons.getResourceId(previousSelectedShapePosition, -1));
            } else {
                ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_sales_shape)).setImageResource(roughShapeSelected.getResourceId(position, 1));

                ((ImageView) parent.getChildAt(previousSelectedShapePosition).findViewById(R.id.img_sales_shape))
                        .setImageResource(roughShapeIcons.getResourceId(previousSelectedShapePosition, -1));
            }
        }
    });
```

UPDATE:
Spinner code snippet on which basis adapter is set

```
  spnShape.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View view, int position, long id) {
                previousSelectedShapePosition = 0;

                if (position == 0) {
                    roughORpolished = 0;
                    adapter = new GridShapeSalesAdapter(AddNewBuyEntryActivity.this, roughShapeItems,roughORpolished);
                    grdShapes.setAdapter(adapter);
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    roughORpolished = 1;
                    adapter = new GridShapeSalesAdapter(AddNewBuyEntryActivity.this, polishedShapeItems,roughORpolished);
                    grdShapes.setAdapter(adapter);
                }


            }
```

here is my gridview adapter

http://pastebin.com/kaU3UFE5

http://pastebin.com/72Uq94dP

Comment: getChildAt() method get the view of shown views in the GridView. Your gridview only can contain 20 elements, so if you call getChildAt(22) it will return null since the there are only 20  visible childs in your gridview

Comment: ive debugged and checked the position im passing to getChildAt doesnt exceed the total number of grid items,the crash occurs when i select a item and then scroll down to select a new item while old item is not in view

Comment: It is because the numbers of childs in GridView doesn't always equals to the number of items in your adapter. This condition is caused of 'recycling' behaviour of android adapters. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works) to understand how 'recycling' behaviour works

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the `View` which is not visible using

```
 parent.getChildAt(previousSelectedShapePosition)
```

When the child is not visible you will get null and as a result NPE.

You need to put some of the logic to `getView`.

**Update**

If you select the item change the background of currently selected view, you will have no problem in this. But don't try to change the background of previously selected item if it's not visible. Rather keep a list of position which background needs to be changed when it becomes visible. Use that list as a check in `getView` and update the background accordingly.

Comment: sorry for noobishness but logic such as?

Comment: Please see my update. A rough step of how you can do it.

Comment: im still confused,even if i maintain a collection of positions and update it ,i need the previous selected position because im changing the src of the imageview of the previous selected as well as of the current selected

Comment: Change the previously selected view's image in `getView` if it's currently not visible. That's all you need to do.

Comment: you mean to say in my adapter i need to check visibility of view and then set it? currently im doing this in my activity. problem is that i have a spinner ,on spinner change i set the adapter again (see updated code),i think thats causing the issue,by default adapter is set for pos 0,on toggling to postion 1 its set again but i think old instance of adapter is there w.r.t to view

Comment: Its simple. Keep track of items you selected in an array or a list. When you click the item changes its background and removal of background should be done in getView if the view is currently not visible. If its visible change the background there only.

Comment: im not changing background im toggling image src on selection and de selection . so say if its background and i select element 3 i can make all the rest black and element 3 red. but in my case on selecting element 3 the previous elements imageviews src has to be set

Comment: sorry i think im not understanding the issue properly myself,il try out what you suggested thanks

Comment: Correct. change the image src on click of currently selected item. But to unselect you need to check if previously selected item is visible or not. If not then change that in getview.